# how to get array of objects from server

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to have a list of objects from a server. But I don't know how to do it exactly and at least print it in System.out.print

server sends data like that:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "15",
        "routeId": "10",
        "driverId": "2",
        "text": "ytf",
        "timestamp": "2018-05-25 13:04:01"
    },
    {
        "userId": "15",
        "routeId": "33",
        "driverId": "2",
        "text": "asd",
        "timestamp": "2018-05-25 13:07:40"
    }
]
```

And model:

- https://pastebin.com/52mc5Gmw
- https://pastebin.com/DnUTtkPC

Controller: https://pastebin.com/ucJFFJyy

And the API:

```
@GET("getReviews.php")
Call<List<reviewResult>> getReview();
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the appropriate code here. For suggestions on creating a good code example, read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, looks like the expected return type should be List of reviewResponse objects. You should change the API to:

```
Call<List<reviewResponse>> getReview();
```

From there it's obvious how to retrieve the data you ask

Comment: i'm getting this:

I/System.out: [dev.busboozted.reviewResponse@2d3e9f68, dev.busboozted.reviewResponse@aabbf81, dev.busboozted.reviewResponse@3e400826, dev.busboozted.reviewResponse@37233c67]

is this an objects? but how to translate them

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) for parse the array, and [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) for get each object of the array

**Edit** Add a example

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                System.out.print(object);

            }
```

Comment: i'm not receiving any data.